# Sorting hybrid bucketed schema in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, comments, database-schema

Our application allows users to create posts and comments. Data is growing fast and we already reviewed Mongodb scaling strategies. We like the approach presented in http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf2011/schemascale , which uses a hybrid schema between embedded and non-embedded documents, bucketing comments so that they are saved in groups of 100 or 200 comments per document.

```
{   
    "_id" : '/post/2323423/1--1',
    "comments" : [{
                "author" : "peter",
                "text"  : "comment!",
                "when" : "June 24 2012,
                "votes": 43
              },
              {
                "author" : "joe",
                "text"  : "hi!",
                "when" : "June 25 2012,
                "votes": 102
              },
              ...
     ],
```

}

By bucketing  comments, fewer disk reads are necessary to display thousands of comments, while at the same time, documents are kept small so writes are fast. It's perfect to paginate comments sorted by date.

We are very interesented in this approach but our application requires comments to be sorted by votes and subcomments.

Currently we use a non-embedded approach which uses a separate collection for comments. Allows us to retrieve data sorted by any field and subcommenting is easy (by reference), but performance is becoming an issue. We would like to use bucketing but the sorting by votes thing does not seem to fit in a bucket.

Sorting by date is trivial, just go for the next bucket as the user clicks 'next page', quering one document. But, how do we manage to do this if we want to sort by votes? we'd have to retrieve all buckets and then sort the comments, which is obviously inneficient...

Any ideas about a proper schema design to accomplish  this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort by descending:

> db.collection.find({},{_id:0}).sort({'comments.votes':1})

Just note that there is a bug where you can only sort by ascending.
See this [bug ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5065)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried an aggregation query?

```
db.commentbuckets.aggregate([
    $match: {discussion_id: <discussion_id>},
    $unwind: "$comments",
    $sort: {votes: -1}
]);
```